# arXiv stamp gets misplaced

Tags: graphics, thesis, arxiv

I'm trying to upload a thesis on arXiv (a single-column A4 document), and the only problem with it is the misplaced arXiv stamp on the title page. I'm providing a mock screenshot of the minimal document it's reproduced with - crucially, the stamp is placed correctly when there's no logo image at the bottom (in the screenshot, a placeholder is in its place.)

UPD: Here's the [MWE code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vI4OOk9xIJT37MEI0GnEaW8QG68NXaiu/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Currently there is not a MWE to view. Since arXiv has their own settings for the article link then it would be better to make a synopsis page first (that will have the link on it) and then start the wide title thesis page.

Comment: You can turn the stamp off: https://arxiv.org/help/00README#nostamp. Other than that one cannot really help you since, as @Leucippus points out, there is no TeX file that one could inspect to give you further advice. (I also doubt that the stamp is done with LaTeX methods.)

Comment: Thanks a lot to you both! I've added the MWE code if it can clarify the problem somewhat. For now, I'll try to go with the no-stamp option.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from the arXiv support:

> The arXiv stamping location is based on an assumption of "letterpaper"
> in the document class. This is failing because you are using A4. The
> solution to this is either to turn off stamping with a 00README.XXX
> files as described at: https://arxiv.org/help/00README#nostamp or
> switching to letterpaper.

And regarding the fact that the stamping is correct when there's no image on the page:

> This is dependent on how the image is being inserted onto the page,
> along with how the system is interpreting where the origin is (and is
> different between pdflatex and latex in our system). In general,
> arXiv’s stamping routine is quite fragile, and encountering too many
> minipages (which is common on thesis and in the book.cls format), can
> cause unexpected results. This is why we suggested just disabling it.